# Print Text with DrawString() next to an existing bitmap

Tags: c#, string, bitmap

Greetings fellow users,

A virgin post on my end since its the first time i am abusing stack overflow with a question! I have been trying to get a bitmap print along with a String to print. Basically the view i want to achieve is the Image and the text to the right of the image as we see the printout. Below is the code I am using

```
 Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
 senderQR = qrCodeImage;

 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

 Margins margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);

 pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
 pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
 pd.Print();
```

Here is the PrintPage method

```
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = senderQR;

        Bitmap batchCode = new Bitmap(80, 700);

        Rectangle m = e.MarginBounds;
        RectangleF batch1 = new RectangleF(80, 700, 650, 1000);

        m.Width = img.Width / 5;
        m.Height = img.Height / 5;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(batchCode);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawString(batch, new Font("Arial", 40), Brushes.Black, batch1);
        g.Flush();

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, m);

    }
```

What am i doing wrong? what seems to be the issue? I have been struggling a whole lot to achieve this but no luck!

Additional Notes:

I want the text on the right to Wrap under itself and not under or on top of the existing bitmap within a size of 3,5 x 2 (inches) (label printing).

This is the printout i get with the existing code;

https://prnt.sc/h1ecb0

https://prnt.sc/h1edex

Comment: I cant see any text in either image, so it is not clear what you are asking.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: " g.DrawString(batch, new Font("Arial", 40), Brushes.Black, batch1);"

Comment: I was referring to `i want to achieve...as we see the printout`.  There is no text in either that I can see

Comment: Just don't use Graphics.FromImage().  That modifies the image and you'll inevitably draw on top of it.  Use e.Graphics.DrawString() instead so you can position the text anywhere you want it on paper.

Comment: I don't understand the negative point in my question. But either the case, thanks for your comments. I have resolved it with the suggestion below. I cannot upvote the correct answer since i dont have enough rep. Thanks again @rs232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you're drawing on (batchCode) is 80 pixels wide and 700 high. When you write your text over it, you set the top-left point of your writing to 80,700 - exactly to the bottom-right corner of your picture. Basically, you write your text outside of the picture.

### Update

I've created a small example to make it reproducible, below is a form class for a basic WinForms application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PictureBox pictureBox2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox2 = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox2.Size = ClientSize;
        pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.Click += Form1_Click;
        pictureBox2.Click += Form1_Click;

        Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var batch = "hello there!";

        Bitmap batchCode = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
        var batch1 = new RectangleF(150, 150, 850, 850);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(batchCode))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawString(batch, new Font("Arial", 40), Brushes.Black, batch1);
        }
        pictureBox2.Image = batchCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: shoot! thank you very much! Silly me! So its the batch1 that needs to adjust right?

Comment: Yes, but you might also need to increase your batchCode image size in order to have some room for your text.

Comment: thanks! i attempted the following changes:
Bitmap batchCode = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
RectangleF batch1 = new RectangleF(150, 150, 1000, 1000);
still cant see the text! what would you suggest

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working example for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It is much appreciated! I managed to print it! I also centered it in the Rectangle and moved it a bit lower to look in the middle but here was the first one i managed to have it appear 
https://prnt.sc/h1raq2